# Lazy load DIV embeded Flickr gallery & skipping it from preload

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading

I am having a bootstrap website with gallery. If I add Flickr gallery embedded, it takes forever to load with preloader.

`<div id="flickrembed">` with a

```
<script src="http://flickrembed.com/embed_v2.js.php?source=flickr&layout=responsive&input=XXXX"></script>
```

I tried to use lazysizes lazyloader plugin, lazysizes unveilhooks extension. But as of now no change.

I removed preloader and the site loads but with some issues (top banner slideshow skipped from loading, which really makes website not looking good)

Kindly help me how to lazy load div element...

Answer (score 0):

i Had the same issue, you need to add 
`</div> after <div id="flickrembed">` 
I checked the code of flickrembed, they use http://unitegallery.net/, I wonder how to do the same as they do without using scripts off their site.